# How can I execute a function every time I insert certain characters in the buffer?

Tags: hooks, text-editing

I write a lot of text in German and English and I'm getting tired of switching the dictionary of my spell-checker all the time.  In true Emacs spirit, I decided to do something about this and dusted off my grandpa's parentheses.  The code I wrote guesses the language of the current paragraph and then changes the language in ispell and typo-mode.  It also reruns flyspell on the current paragraph, but only on that paragraph because sometimes I also write documents in multiple languages.

All this is working really nicely and I will publish this code after some more testing, so other people can use it, too.  However, I want the process of switching languages to be fully automatic so I don't have to think about it at all.  This means that my function should run every once in a while during text editing.  Perhaps it's overkill to run it on every key stroke but I thought it might be good to run it every time I start a new word, i.e., when I enter a space or newline.  Alternatively, it might also be enough to run it only when I enter punctuation marks.

**My question:** How can I fire off the function when certain characters are inserted in the buffer?  Is there a hook for that?  Thanks for your help.

FYI: Here is my code: https://github.com/tmalsburg/guess-language.el

Comment: `post-self-insert-hook` fires after every insert, but could be made to work by doing the check for the character in the hook.

Comment: @wasamasa But how do I know which character was inserted?

Comment: Oh, it's simply the character at point I guess. That was too easy for me ;-)

Comment: Not a direct answer but another approach might be to run on a timer, or whenever Emacs is idle for a few seconds. See `run-with-idle-timer` and `run-with-timer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple function that you can use to check if the
character you just entered should set off your
`do-my-awesome-thing` function:

```el
(defun do-awesome-thing-maybe ()
  (when (memq (char-before) '(?\  ?\t))
    (message "You should do-my-awesome-thing now")))
```

Here, it checks if the character you just entered was either a
space or a tab (which seems like a reasonable compromise between
doing it after every character, which is probably overkill, and
doing it on a timer, which would require you to stop typing for a
while).  If so, you would `do-my-awesome-thing`.  You can then
add it to the hook:

```el
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'do-awesome-thing-maybe)
```

Comment: It works, very nice. Unfortunately, it turns out that running flyspell-region on the paragraph every time a space is entered is a little too slow.  I can also see the cursor running through the paragraph which is distracting. Probably also drains the battery of my notebook. Hm ...

Comment: @tmalsburg: you could probably modify it to check if you've started a new paragraph so that you'll only do it once by text block.

Comment: I see that flyspell has a `flyspell-incorrect-hook`. If you're already using flyspell to find errors on the fly, maybe you could use that hook to check (and possibly change) the language when flyspell finds an incorrect word?

Comment: @dan When I start a new paragraph there is no text yet to guess the language.  The algorithm takes about six words of material to distinguish reasonably well between English and German.  I could run flyspell when I finish a paragraph but that's too late and I'd have to look at many underlined words.

Comment: @glucas That's a great idea.  I'll try it.

Comment: @tmalsburg: interesting.  Another option would be to keep a state variable that counts the number of spaces entered and then run `do-my-thing` once the count hits, say, 5 or 6, after which it resets.  Good idea on the `flyspell-incorrect-hook`, though, which may end up being cleaner.

Comment: @Dan  Unfortunately, I can't run flyspell in flyspell-incorrect-hook because that gives me an endless recursion.  Do I have to run flyspell with a timer asynchonously?

Comment: No, running asynchronously still triggers an endless loop.

Comment: @tmalsburg: it might make sense to post a new question along the lines of "I need to run an expensive function every once in a while, how do I do it?"  It'll get more views (and hopefully help!) than these comments will get.  Plus, that question will probably be useful to others as well.

Comment: Right. Got a little too excited. Thanks for you input.

Comment: @tmalsburg You may be able to prevent the recursive loop by keeping some additional state. Basically, you want a flyspell error to trigger your custom function unless it is already running. So you might check some buffer-local variable; if it is false, set it to true and schedule your custom function to do its thing and reset the flag when it is done. (Something along those lines...) :-)

Comment: @glucas Thank you.  I solved it by removing the hook for temporarily and then reinserting it after flyspell is finished.

Comment: @tmalsburg I see you made this available on melpa -- cool!